# LeJOS extension for NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, lejos-nxj

I am new to Lejos and have a short question.Is there any LeJOS extension to combine with NetLogo? I need to run Lejos with Netlogo and plugged both of them into Eclipse.But I cant use Netlogo as I wanted in java.So I want to  know whether it is possible to add LeJOS into Netlogo as extension .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of any such extension. It should possible to build one use the NetLogo extensions API though; see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API